# Subsampling R arrays to produce interesting spatial orientations

Tags: r, sample

I wonder if there's a straightforward way to subsample an array in R = such that we can get interesting orientations (e.g., orientation A in the attached figure).

[image]

The array that I am dealing with can be quite large (e.g., 10000 (rows) x 100 (columns))

The ability to do so easily is relevant to incorporating spatial structure in the form of neighbourhoods into evolutionary algorithms (specifically cellular EAs for instance).

An obvious, but not the most efficient solution, would be to specify the array indices to sample.

Comment: Please provide more details on the sampling procedure. Provide a concise definition of 'interesting'. Make your example reproducible and show us what you have tried. Cheers

Comment: `sample` is for sampling randomly from a set, with or without replacement. I can't tell from your code-less question if your goal is to use `sample` to select these very non-random subsets of an array (if so, the answer is *"Yes, you can do this, but you'll need to try out a whole lot of random seeds to find a lucky one. Can't imagine why you'd want to."*), or if you want to sample from within these "interesting" orientations with `sample`, in which case I'm curious what you think an "ideal" solution would be.

Comment: @Gregor I think I may just take a random subsample with probability weights without replacement from the larger array. Yes, it likely won't correspond to the "interesting" orientations above, as these are nonrandom arrangements, but it's a quick and dirty fix for the time being.